# Computer Vision and Similarity Transform between two images

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, svd, computer-vision

for a small project I need to compute the similarity transformation matrix which transforms 2d coordinates from one image (left image) in another image (right image).
I know that the right image is generated from the left image by applying a similarity transformation (rotation, translation).
Further I know that the following relation between a point from the left image (u,v) and a point from the right image (u',v') (a match) holds:

$$
\begin{align}
   \begin{bmatrix}
      u' \\
      v'
   \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
      a & -b & c \\
      b & a & d
   \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
      u \\
      v \\
      1
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

We have now 4 unknowns => we need to collect 4 points (2 matches) and get the following equations:
$$
u_0' = au_0 - bv_0 + c\\
v_0' = bu_0 + av_0 + d\\
u_1' = au_1 - bv_1 + c\\
v_1' = bu_1 + av_1 + d
$$

My question is now how to bring this in a form where the SVD can be applied to find the best similarity matrix.

Thank you!

*edit*
Attention: The matches might be noisy - in other words, not all matches follow exactly the same transformation.

Comment: You have a system of linear equations in the entries of the transformation matrix. Rewrite that system in matrix form, effectively “flattening” the transformation matrix into a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system of equations is already in matrix form ($4\times4$).

There is no benefit using an SVD, Gaussian elimination is good enough, as the solution is exact.

Comment: I think that the solution will not be perfect, since the matches are noisy. I would assume that a optimization is necessary. Therefore a SVD might be a possibility.

Comment: @bobby: you said you were using two pairs of points. If true, SVD is pointless. In any case, this system is already in matrix form.